# Can I truncate decimals in Java?

Tags: java, decimal-point

I have this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecimalPoints {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("a: ");               // printing output
        String text_1 = scanner.nextLine();      // taking input
        double d1 = Double.parseDouble(text_1);  // parsing double from input  

        System.out.println("b: ");               // printing output
        String text_2 = scanner.nextLine();      // taking input
        double d2 = Double.parseDouble(text_2);  // parsing double from input

        double d3 = d1 / d2;

        d3 = Math.round(d3 * 100) / 100.0d;

        System.out.println("Result: " + d3);
    }
}
```

It takes two inputs and rounds it up to two decimal places but the problem is that it rounds up the result. Let's say that I enter a = 513 and b = 791 the result would be 0.65 but when I  check my calculator it shows me 0.648...Does anyone know how to leave the number just at 0.64? Much Obliged.

Comment: What do you want it to do if `d3` is negative?

Comment: no... d3 works just fine I just want d3 to spit out the result without rounding the number up for instance if 513 is divided by 791 I want ti to display 0.64 and not 0.65. Get it now?

Comment: My question was to work out whether you wanted to round ALWAYS DOWNWARDS (like `Math.floor` does) or always TOWARDS ZERO (like just dropping the decimals off the number, which seemed to be closer to your description).  They are different if `d3` is negative.  Repeating what you had already said didn't really cover the case that you had omitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe use `Math.floor()` instead of `Math.round()`?

Comment: U are the man sir!!! It works!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [java.math.BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).